# .toLocaleTimeString() syntax not displaying AM/PM in safari browser

Tags: javascript, time, datetime-format, time-format

I wanted to change the format of a time to HH:mm AM/PM by using javascript.
Then I used `.toLocaleTimeString()` syntax to format it.
But it's not working as expected ***in safari browser*** when working correctly on google chrome.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

I tried as bellow,

```
time = dateStr.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');
```

expected output was => 11:15 AM
but output in safari browser was => 11:15

Comment: It's working fine for me in Safari? What is `dateStr`?

Comment: dateStr is avariable that value like 'Thu Oct 27 2022 04:18:39 GMT+0530'

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1')` works in Safari. Is `dateStr` a JavaScript `Date` object?

Comment: Yes. "dateStr = new Date(dateStr);"

Comment: Display the time correctly. But missing AM/PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was founded a solution for this case,

```
time = dateStr.toLocaleTimeString('en-US').replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');
```

I added 'en-US' to the syntax. Now it's working correctly in both safari and chrome browsers.